# Docker Container Connecting To Host MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, docker, host

I was following along a docker tutorial that used a container for MySQL. That worked, but I am trying to connect to my host's MySQL from a php/apache container.

I created a database called 'weather', a user 'admin'@'%' and granted the user all privileges to the weather database. I also created the necessary table/columns.

However, I keep getting the following message:

**Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/index.php on line 15
Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection refused**

Here's where the php app inside the container fails the connection:

```
<?php require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// Create a new Container
$container = new \Slim\Container([
    // Add Guzzle as 'http'
    'http' => function () {
        return new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    },
    // Add mysqli as 'mysql'
    'mysql' => function () {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(
            getenv('DATABASE_HOST'),
            getenv('DATABASE_USER'),
            getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
            getenv('DATABASE_NAME')
        );
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            exit;
        } else {
            return $mysqli;
        }
    },
]);
```

I installed all the dependencies with composer and bound my host's ip address (172.17.0.1) in my.cnf. Here's the docker command I'm running:

```
docker run -d --rm --name=weather-app -p 38000:80 -v \ 
$(pwd):/var/www/html \
 -e DATABASE_HOST='172.17.0.1' \
 -e DATABASE_USER='admin' \ 
 -e DATABASE_PASSWORD='password' \
 -e DATABASE_NAME='weather' \
 shiphp/weather-app
```

Here's the git repo if more info is needed: https://github.com/shiphp/weather-app.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I figured out what's going on. I forgot to add the  [mysqld] header in my.cnf when I bound the address. It works now.

Comment: do you have mysql running on 172.17.0.1?

Comment: Do you really have docker interface with inet addr:172.17.0.1?